# Android ListView: Show two ListViews with no spaces

Tags: android, android-listview

I have two `ListViews`: `listview` and `listview1`. `listview` contains 7-8 columns and the last column contain an `EditText`.  I want to show two `ListView`s with no spaces and they should be filled.

Here is my code:

## XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ShowTwoListView">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvFoods"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvRestaurants"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

## Items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivFoods"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your sub view needs to match its parents width

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivFoods"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```